# Unity TextMeshPro text and string are not the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically i'm trying to compare two strings like this;

```
    public void OnJoinRoom(TextMeshProUGUI roomName)
    {
        Debug.Log("|"+roomName.text+"|");

        string normalString = "123";

        if (roomName.text == normalString)
        {
            Debug.Log("SAME TEXT");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("NOT SAME TEXT");
        }
        PhotonModel.JoinReservedRoom(roomName.text);
    }
```

OnJoinRoom fires when a user clicks to my "Join" button and it gets room name from an textmeshpro input field. In summary, i try to create room and other user types the room name and joins. When I try to create room with name "123" and join with the "normalString", it joins the room. But when i get the value from roomName and try to join, it fails. I'm sure i type "123" to the input field. Here is the Console Log.

[image: Example]

I could not find any solutions online. I could really use a help here :)

EDIT:

Console Log with roomName length.

[image]

Comment: could you also log `roomName.text.Length` ? ... it may contains `(char)8203` which is ZeroWidthSpace ... you may use `string.Trim(char)` to remove it

Comment: @Selvin Never thought of that. I edited the question and added length. It is 4 instead of 3.  Let me try what you suggested.

Comment: hehe ... it was result of quick google search "TextMeshProUGUI.text strange character"

Comment: Wow it worked. I do not understand how that worked thought. Can you post this as your answer please. Thank you very much. I would appreciate if you could give more details about why this solved the issue.

Comment: Alternatively, make sure that `roomName` refers to the **TMP_InputField** component, and **not** the **TMP_Text** child component.

Comment: @Ruzihm You know my soul. I was indeed getting the value from the child. I'm changing it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `roomName` refers to the **TMP_InputField** component (or its equivalent), and not the **TMP_Text** child component (or its equivalent), which may contain formatting characters.

Comment: You're right child component contains ZeroWidthSpace as @Selvin mentioned. This way is more cleaner.